# Make operator in Beam independent on Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am currently running the Nexmark benchmark suites within Apache Beam for Google Dataflow, and I want to customize it a bit for what I need.

More specifically, I am testing for the autoscaling capabilities of Dataflow given my custom workload, and I want the workload generator to be independent as to not have it succumb to backpressure and slow down.

The current code for event generation looks like this:

```java
  /** Return source of events from Pubsub. */
  private PCollection<Event> sourceEventsFromPubsub(Pipeline p) {
    NexmarkUtils.console("Reading events from Pubsub %s", pubsubSubscription);

    PubsubIO.Read<PubsubMessage> io =
        PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()
            .fromSubscription(pubsubSubscription)
            .withIdAttribute(NexmarkUtils.PUBSUB_ID);
    if (!configuration.usePubsubPublishTime) {
      io = io.withTimestampAttribute(NexmarkUtils.PUBSUB_TIMESTAMP);
    }

    return p.apply(queryName + ".ReadPubsubEvents", io)
        .apply(queryName + ".PubsubMessageToEvent", ParDo.of(new PubsubMessageEventDoFn()));
  }
```

Is there documentation on how I can modify this to run on its exclusive worker? Kind of like Flink's `slotSharingGroup` ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your pipeline into 2 pipelines: one reads Pub/Sub -> generates events -> writes to an intermediate Pub/Sub topic and another consumes the events through the intermediate Pub/Sub topic.

Other than that, there is no way to explicitly control how Dataflow provisions resources for different stages of a pipeline.